# How to build the following query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a web application about gift lists in Rails 3. I'd would like to get all the purchases for a certain list. These are the models and their relationships:

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  has_many :purchases

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gifts

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gift
```

So, basically, I've tried the following code (I don't think it's the best way to do this at all), and eventhough the results are correct, I've realized that I get a `Gift` object instead of a `Purchase`:

```
@purchases = List.find(params[:id]).gifts.joins(:purchases).select("purchases.*")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@purchases = List.find(params[:id]).
                  gifts.joins(:purchases).
                  map(&:purchases).flatten
```

or just refactor your models:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gifts
  has_many :purchases, :through => :gifts
```

so

```
List.find(params[:id]).purchases
```

Comment: That what I was looking for! I've added the :purchases relation to the List model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the purchases maybe...

```
@purchases= List.find(params[:id]).gifts.collect{|g| g.purchases}
```

Although you may want to split it up and check that List.find returns a valid List.

Comment: Although I prefer the refactor that @fl00r answered